# Google Chart API and AdoDB PHP

Tags: php, object, google-visualization, adodb

I wonder if anyone knows a way to integrate the class for PHP ADODB with the Google Chart API.
I've tried several ways, but have not found something practical, I wanted to create a class where I could connect to the database (using PostgreSQL), and have underlying functions in this class to convert data and / or array in requests for graphics google...

thanks!!

Comment: The easiest approach is probably to create a class that accepts a SQL query and returns a JSON string representation of a DataTable object.  I'm not familiar with the PHP ADODB library, but it is likely to be conceptually similar to the PDO library, which I am familiar with.  If you could share some code that you have tried so far, I can work with you to get it into a usable form for the Visualization API.

Answer (score 0):

In general your best bet is to handle this through composition.

Conceptually you have class A which has the following members:

1. A Google API-interop class or interface
2. An ADODB class/interface.

Then you basically use your class to mediate between these two.  The specific API you offer to your application will of course depend on what you are trying to do.  You may also, depending on what you are doing, want to have the ADODB wrapped in another class that returns a singleton.